# In-memory file type objects in Clojure

Tags: clojure, java-io

I'm just getting started with Clojure and would like to call a Java method that takes as arguments an input file to read and an output file to which to write.  Both appear to be of type java.io.File.  The method I would like to call is "parse" in this class:

http://htmltolatex.sourceforge.net/javadoc/cz/kebrt/html2latex/Parser.html

However, because I will be calling the method repeatedly, I would prefer to use in-memory objects rather than files on disk.

I have successfully loaded an instance of the Parser class with:

```
(def my_parser (cz.kebrt.html2latex.Parser.))
```

I believe that I have successfully created an in-memory file-like object from which to read using this command:

```
(def input-object (java.io.StringBufferInputStream. "this is a test"))
```

However, what kind of file like object should I pass to capture the output?  (For the sake of completeness, I should mention that this output file is first used to construct an instance of ParserHandler, which is then passed to the parser created above.  http://htmltolatex.sourceforge.net/javadoc/cz/kebrt/html2latex/ParserHandler.html)

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this (badly-designed) API is for an old version of the software which doesn't allow what you want to do. (i.e. you can't create a `File` whose contents is in-memory. That's not what the class is for.)

The [latest version](http://htmltolatex.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/htmltolatex/src/cz/kebrt/html2latex/parser/Parser.java?revision=15&view=markup) appears to have a constructor to which you can pass either a `java.io.File` or a `String`. The latter should be what you're after.

edit: I think it might be nice to clear up some stuff for you, since you seem to be coming from a Python background (given your repeated use of the term "file-like"). `java.io.File` is a misleading name. Its actually more like a path. For example, if you want to check if a file exists, you'd do `(.exists (java.io.File. "my/path"))`. A `File` can also be a directory. It's dumb I know, but hey, it's java. (If you want to know more, look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)). What this Parser class should really be providing is the ability to pass a `java.io.Reader`, which is like an abstract view over a sequence of characters. Internally they convert both the `String` option and the `File` option to a `Reader`, so its really bad design that they don't just accept a reader and cut out the middle man.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, D.J.  And yes, I am coming from Python.

Comment: I reinstalled the java program from svn into my Clojure project as you suggested. Does this call look correct now? (It is throwing errors, for me):  (cz.kebrt.html2latex.Parser. "this is a test")

Comment: Well first, the class has been moved to `cz.kebrt.html2latex.parser.Parser`, and second, I had a proper poke around the source and I'm not sure that it does what you want when constructed with a String. In this case, it creates a default ParserHandler, which, as far as I can tell, won't be outputting anything to anywhere. My best guess is that they use it for unit tests. I don't think you can do what you want without modifying the source. If you do want to modify the source, it might be OK to just create a new constructor that takes a `String` and a `ParserHandler`. I can't guarantee it though